# iphone - using a UISwitch

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to implement a view where I need the user to answer several questions using YES or NO. I thought of using a UISwitch but as far as I see it does not allows replacing the ON/OFF messages it shows with YES/NO. Am I wrong?

I thought of implementing a segmented control with 2 buttons but this is like using a cannon to kill a fly...

Any suggestions on how to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make custom "Yes" & "No" buttons that get selected when pushed.

This way, you'll have more control on the design and you'll be safe from Apple rejection.

Answer (score 3):

ArsTechnica: [Robust UISwitch label swaps](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/03/iphone-dev-robust-uiswitch-label-swaps.ars)

Comment: I suppose I will be nailed by apple for doing this... my app will be probably rejected. what do you think?

Comment: +1, but I think it would be better to come with a custom control.